# Message from SQL Server database to application when something changes in database

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I have used triggers within a database .. like  .. when record in table A is deleted then also delete the corresponding record in table B, C D .. e.c.t

In SQL Server, is there a way to send message to application from database using triggers ...

The scenario is ...

If same application ( .exe ) is opened by 2 users and both use the same database ... then is 1st user has deleted an item ... then 2nd user should see it immediately ... or something like that.

Comment: @KK - I posted an answer that was assuming you were using .Net as your dev platform - you may want to specify what environments you will be using on the application side and also tag this question with the appropriate app environment tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Query Notifications.
See:
[MS Sql 2008 Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175110.aspx)
[MS Sql 2005 Using Query Notifications With C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555893)